# How to put a video like an image

Tags: ios, swift, video, uiscrollview

I have an image gallery (I use UIScrollView to slide the image).
How to put a video inside that gallery like an image ?
The user will be able to slide the video like an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one framework called [AVFoundation](https://developer.apple.com/av-foundation/) try to use it to show video in one subview. After that you can put your view anywhere you want.
For more help you can start by running some examples, watch WWDC videos and read the documentation. All of this is in the link above.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple would be to use [Player](https://github.com/piemonte/Player). Usage described on the github readme file.

But as the other answer suggest AVFoundation would give you more freedom at the expanse of implementation time.